# Get error code 14 when sending SMS using smsapi

Tags: php, api, sms

I am trying to send SMS using the API from smsapi.pl. Currently I am getting error code 14 which means "Invalid sender field".

Code:

```
        $access_token = 'XXXXXX';          //sms api access token
        $numbers = '+7XXXXXXXX';
        $params = array(
            'to'            => $numbers,       
            'from'          => 'Info',    
            'message'       => 'message text',      
            );

        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.smsapi.pl/sms.do');
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
              "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"
        ));

        $content = curl_exec($c);
        $http_status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($c);
        print_r($content);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translated [documentation](https://www.smsapi.pl/docs/#biblioteki) says:

> Only verified names are accepted. (& from = aktywna_nazwa). The sender field should be added after logging in to the SMSAPI website, Sender Field .

Did you add the sender name `Info` on the [website](https://ssl.smsapi.pl/sms_settings/sendernames)?